# Is there a way to "cast" Data to [UInt8] (a byte array) without copying, or is Unsafe the way to go?

Tags: arrays, swift, byte, nsdata

I know I can do

```
//Setup
let originalBytes: [UInt8] = [0x0, 0x1, 0x2]
let originalData = Data(originalBytes)

//This
let getByteArFromData: [UInt8] = [UInt8](originalData)
```

Now, I'm *pretty* sure that `getByteArFromData` COPIES the bytes into new allocated memory (am I wrong here?).

That gets *expensive* as the data scales (e.g. images, codec manipulation, etc.).

I am motivated to ask this question because I would like to manipulate data through an array-like interface, but as far as I know, the Unsafe API is the way to go. So...

Is using the Unsafe API the only way to do this? Is it the *recommended* way to do this?

I've played with some pointer arithmetic too (just getting into the Unsafe API, not sure if I should invest the time if I can use an array-like interface).

Here's some playground code (please critique it and answer the questions in the comments if you'd be so kind):

```
import Foundation

//MARK:- Setup

final class PlaygroundSwingSet
{
    //Squish unimportant setup code
    private let byteAr: [UInt8]
    private lazy var data: Data = {Data(byteAr)}()
    init(_ bytes: [UInt8]) {self.byteAr = bytes}

    func swing() -> Int
    {
        //Unsafe API stuff
        return data.withUnsafeBytes {(dataBufferPtr) -> (Int) in   //No need for [weak self], right?
            //I don't like how the pointers are only valid in this closure.
            //It adds an indent to my code to which my "code OCD" forces me to abstract out
            self.middleOut(dataBufferPtr)
        }
    }

    private func middleOut(_ dataBufferPtr: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) -> Int
    {
        //Yuck, I have to make sure count isn't 0 AND safely unwrap.
        //Why is .baseAddress even optional then?
        guard let dataPtr = dataBufferPtr.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), dataBufferPtr.count > 0 else {
            print("data is empty")
            return 0
        }
        let middishIndex = dataBufferPtr.count / 2 - 1

        //More yuck.
        print("truncated middle element's value is \(dataPtr.advanced(by: middishIndex).pointee)")
        print("this should yield the same thing: \((dataPtr + middishIndex).pointee)")
        return middishIndex
    }
}

//MARK:- Code Execution

let a = PlaygroundSwingSet([0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4]).swing() //a = 1
//Console prints
/*
 truncated middle element's value is 3
 this should yield the same thing: 2
 */
let b = PlaygroundSwingSet([]).swing()  //b = 0
//Console prints
/*
 data is empty
 */
```

Comment: `Data` is a  `(RandomAccess)Collection` and as such already has an “array-like interface”.

Comment: Why exactly do you want an `Array<UInt8>`? What does it do that `Data` doesn't already do?

Comment: Well, now that I know Data has subscript access, nothing! For a personal project, I'm writing a program that converts H.264 AVCC data that VideoToolbox generates into H.264 AVCC Annex B. I have to rewrite the bytes that precede each block of data to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to cast Data because it supports the [subscript operator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1780340-subscript) to access the `UInt8` at a given index.

Incidentally it also supports `isEmpty`, so you do not need to check if count is 0.

```
var data = Data(repeating: 0, count: 5)
data.indices.forEach { data[$0] = UInt8($0) }
print(data[2])
```

Comment: Not “incidentally” but as part of the (RandomAccess)Collection conformance :)